# Password_verify resturns false after some time

Tags: php

My problem is that password_verify (php) used with password_hash will return false after some time. It works properly at first (the right password returns true and a wrong pw resturns false). My login form works just as I want it to. But after some days suddenly the password and the hash don't match anymore. Neither the password nor the hash (recorder in database) have been changed.
Then when I reset the same password it works again. I don't understand what happens...

I record the password in the database with a prepared statement and password_hash:

```
$inscr = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO membres (pseudo,motdepasse,email,sexe) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
$inscr->execute(array(htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudo']),password_hash(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password1']),PASSWORD_BCRYPT),htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']),$_POST['sexe']));
$inscr->closeCursor();
```

Then with the login form I test the password with password_verify:

```
if(password_verify($_POST['login_password'],$login_data['motdepasse'])!==true)
    {
    [will report error message]
    }

else if (password_verify($_POST['login_password'],$login_data['motdepasse'])==true)
    {
    [will connect user]
    }
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Messing with the password when you store it using `password_hash(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password1']),PASSWORD_BCRYPT)` Has every likelyhood of changing the password!!!!!!! _Dont fiddle with whats been entered, its gona get hashed anyway, so what the point of fiddling with it_

Comment: Password check is overly complicated, try a simple `if(password_verify($_POST['login_password'],$login_data['motdepasse'])) { // its OK } else {// its wrong}`

Comment: Or `if( ! password_verify($_POST['login_password'],$login_data['mot‌​depasse'])) { // its Wrong } else {// its OK}`

Comment: Thanks you're right. Still this doesn't solve my problem... Is there a chance that the hash is altered at some time in the database ?